# Get image with Url.Action and stream to PDF (ASP.NET MVC 3 C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, stream

I'm trying to stream images to a View and make a PDF file of it.

This is my (Partial) CSHTML file:

```
@if (TempData["foto"] != null)
{
    <p>
        @Html.Raw(TempData["foto"] + "")
    </p>
}
```

In the controller I'm using this code to fill TempData["foto"]:

```
TempData["foto"] = "<img src = \"" + Url.Action("getImage", "base", new { @type = "machine", @val = sqlOnderhoud.First().machine_id }) + "\" class = \"imgMachine\" alt = \"Afbeelding machine\" />";
```

The code in BaseController/getImage is:

```
public ActionResult getImage(string type, string val)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(type) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(val))
    {
        string filePath = String.Empty;

    if (type == "machine")
    {
        filePath = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["upload_path"] + "\\machines\\" + val + ".jpg";
    }
    else if (type == "handtekening")
    {
        filePath = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["upload_path"] + "\\handtekeningen\\" + val + ".jpg";
    }

    FileStream stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    FileStreamResult result = new FileStreamResult(stream, "image/png");
    result.FileDownloadName = type + "-" + val + ".png";

    return result;
}
else
{
    return View();
}
```

}

When i stream the image to the screen without creating a PDF of it, it will show my image. BUt when I open the PDF file afterwards, there is a broken image...
I think it's because the base/getImage is not executed when it's read as plain text.

To get the HTML string I use this code:

```
string body = string.Empty;

using (var sw = new StringWriter())
{
    var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, "TemplatePDF/onderhoud_rapportage");
    var viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
    viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
    viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(ControllerContext, viewResult.View);

    body = sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
}
```

Code that makes the PDF:

```
byte[] pdfBytes = pdfConverter.GetPdfBytesFromHtmlString(htmlString, para.baseURL);
```

Hopefully someone can help me to get the image in the PDF file too!

Kind Regards,
Dennis

PS: The reason why I stream images, is because of the fact the images are outside of the Content folder, they're on another HDD...

Comment: What is pdfConverter?

Comment: It's Html To PDF software, but I found the solution in the meanwhile... because the PDF is created on the server i could link the file from station D:\ and it shows my image in the PDF now!

Comment: Please, answer yourself, and mark as answer. In that way it will be useful for other people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed:
Because the PDF is created on the server I could link the file from station D:\ and it shows my image in the PDF now!